# display large query results on page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am wanting to perform paging without having to call the database for the next set of information.  the queries currently (for a typical query) take a little while (a few minutes) to return results, and so i don't want to set up paging that will continually ping the database for the data.  I want to utilize the data currently in a `DataTable` object and just page through that.  I'm assuming I would use something like `Javascript` to peform this, however my experience with`Javascript` has not been very extensive and so I don't know how this would work.

as an example of the content right now the testing query returns about 6,500 rows with about 30 columns worth of data.

I'm using `ASP.NET` and currently using webforms.  Haven't transitioned everything over to MVC as of yet.

Comment: I dont know the reason you want to do this, bet the best way is paging

Answer (score 0):

If you are using classic .NET all you have to do is pass your dataset into a gridview control and set allow paging to true.

[Gridview.AllowPaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: doesn't a `GridView` query the database every time the user clicks the next page?  This is what I'm wanting to avoid.

Comment: Yes, it does.  However you could use [output caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3w8402y(v=vs.90).aspx) and pull the whole shebang in your initial dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If your saying you just want to run your query, put the data into a datatable and then display it to the user in a datagrid and have paging then you can set the following properties:

```
AllowPaging="true"
PageSize="10" //Use to display however many records you want per page.
OnPageIndexChanged="dgMyGrid_PageIndexChanged" //Use this to go to the correct page
```

Then create a PagerStyle (inside your DataGrid tags), below is an example:

```
<PagerStyle PrevPageText="< Prev " 
           NextPageText=" Next >" 
           Font-Bold="true"
           HorizontalAlign="Center" 
           Mode="NextPrev" />
```

For your OnPageIndexChanged event you could then have something like:

```
protected void dgMyGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dgMyGrid.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    dgMyGrid.DataSource = MyDataTable;
    dgMyGrid.DataBind();
}
```

However, with so many records you might want to look into custom pagination. This [aritcle](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx) might help.

Comment: With this would I need to make sure that the `DataTable` is somehow preserved?  I'm assuming that when you "page" this would cause the page to reload.  otherwise I'm still in that state of querying the database every time the user "pages".

Comment: Yes you would. You could create your data table as a page variable, fill it and then use it to repopulate your data grid on paging.